# Java - Calling an ArrayList to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

Quick back story, I'm doing an assignment for my AP class and I'm trying to figure out why this is giving me an error. Been looking on here for a few hours now and have given up on finding out what to do. I am having trouble when trying to use insertPosition() giving me the error java.util.ArrayList can not be converted to Candidate. Here is my code so far:

```
public class TestCandidate
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList <Candidate> election = new ArrayList<Candidate>(1000);
        election.add(new Candidate("John Smith", 5000));
        election.add(new Candidate("Mary Miller", 4000));
        election.add(new Candidate("Michael Duffy", 6000));
        election.add(new Candidate("Tim Robinson", 2500));
        election.add(new Candidate("Joe Ashtony", 1800));
        election.add(new Candidate("Mickey Jones", 3000));
        election.add(new Candidate("Rebecca Morgan", 2000));
        election.add(new Candidate("Kathleen Turner", 8000));
        election.add(new Candidate("Tory Parker", 500));
        election.add(new Candidate("Ashton Davis", 10000));
        printResults(election);
    }
    public static int getTotal(ArrayList<Candidate> election){
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; election.size() > i; i++){
            total += election.get(i).getVotes();
        }
        return total;
    }
    public static void printResults(ArrayList<Candidate> election){
        double percent;
        System.out.printf("%-10s\t%-4s\t%-5s\n","Names","Votes","Percent of Votes");
        for(int g = 0; g<2; g++){
            for(int i = 0; election.size() > i; i++){
                percent = (double)election.get(i).getVotes() / getTotal(election)*100;
                System.out.printf("%10s\t%4d\t%5.2f\n",election.get(i).getNames(),election.get(i).getVotes(), percent);
            }
            System.out.print("Total votes: " + getTotal(election));
            election.add(election.get(g).insertPosition(election, g));
        }
    }
}
```

and the second class

```
public class Candidate
{
    public int votes;
    public String name;
    public String newName;
    public Candidate(String a, int b){
        votes = b;
        name = a;
    }

    public int getVotes(){
        return votes;
    }
    public String getNames(){
        return name;
    }
    public int changeVotes(){
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Mickey Jones")){
            votes = 2500;
        }
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Kathleen Turner")){
            votes = 8500;
        }
        return votes;
    }
    public String changeName(){
        newName = name;
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Michael Duffy")){
            newName = "John Elmos";
            System.out.println("\nChanging " + name + " to " + newName + "\n");
        }
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Kathleen Turner")){
            newName = "John Kennedy";
            System.out.println("\nChanging " + name + " to " + newName + "\n");
        }
        return newName;
    }
    public ArrayList<Candidate> insertPosition(ArrayList<Candidate> election, int turn){
        if(turn == 1){
            newName = "Woody Pride";
            votes = 19300;
            election.add(5, new Candidate(newName, votes));
        }
        if(turn == 2){
            newName = "Joy Anderson";
            votes = 1100;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < election.size(); i++){
            if(election.get(i).getNames().equalsIgnoreCase("Kathleen Turner")){
                i = 1000;
                election.add(5, new Candidate(newName, votes));
            }
        }
        return election;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name + " has " + votes + " votes.";
    }
}
```

Comment: insertPosition returns an arraylist.... you are adding the result of that call into the election arraylist...thus you are trying to add an arraylist into an arraylist that can only contain Candidates (and any child classes etc)

Comment: When you overcomplicate things and try to add a bunch of code in one line like `election.add(election.get(g).insertPosition(election, g));`, it is easy to get confused on what is happening.. so split that line into multiple

Comment: `election.addAll(election.get(g).insertPosition(election, g));` because `insertPosition` returns an `ArrayList`